# swift ошибка при компиляции

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь перевернуть массив чисел, но появляется такая ошибка в чем может быть проблема?

```
    func arrayFlip(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var arr = [Int]()

    for i in array {
        arr[i]
    }
    return arr.reversed()
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arrayFlip(array: arr1)
```

Ошибка:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
>   The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: На 44 строчке вы обращаетесь к пустому массиву, по этому и происходит ошибка

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: все разобрался спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
 func arrayFlip(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var arrayElements = [Int]()

    for i in array {
        arrayElements += [i]
    }
    return arrayElements.sorted().reversed()
}

var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15]
print(arrayFlip(array: array1))
```

Вот исправленный пример

Answer (score 0):

1) ошибка из-за того, что есть обращение к элементу массива по несуществующему в нём индексу
*- конкретно в этом участке кода идёт обращение к элементу массива arr по индексу i, но ведь массив arr пуст, вот и ошибка*

```
for i in array {
    arr[i]
}
```

2) можно этот код написать следующим образом:

```
func arrayFlip(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let tmpArra = array //данная инициализация необходима, т.к. дальнейшие операции сортировки и реверса элементов массива не могут производиться над массивом, который передан в качестве параметра метода
    return tmpArra.sorted().reversed()
}
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15]
print(arrayFlip(array: array1)) // [15, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```